# How to change the prompt in putty

Tags: unix, shell, prompt

when i start putty on a server
i get the promp like below:

```
hpbl802!benjaminb:~ [22]>
```

How can i change this prompt to

```
benjamin:~ [22]>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not Putty, it's your shell that gives you the prompt.  If you are using bash, try:

```
PS1='benjamin:\w [\!]> '
export PS1
```

If that works, you can add the two lines to your `$HOME/.bashrc` on the server.

More information on [bash prompts](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt).

If your shell is not bash, you need to tell us what shell it is.  The easiest way is to type a non-existent command on the command-line:

```
$ 42
-bash: 42: command not found
```

The above tells me that my shell is bash.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding "benjamin", it's better to use `\u` which pulls in the username.

Comment: @Dennis: I would have suggested `\u`, but didn't because his username seems to be `benjaminb` and he wants `benjamin`.